# Robolectric RuntimeEnvironment.application is deprecated, where is ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-9.0-pie

I switched to [Robolectric 4.0 Beta 1](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-4.0-beta-1) from [3.8](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/releases/tag/robolectric-3.8) because I need compatibility with Android 9 (API 28).

With this change, [`RuntimeEnvironment.application`](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.8/org/robolectric/RuntimeEnvironment.html#application) is now deprecated.

The replacement is apparently to use:

`androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()`

I have no idea where exactly this code is. It must be within a separate dependency entirely. Where is it? How do I add it to my project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As described in the [Robolectric Migration Guide to 4.0](http://robolectric.org/migrating/) you have to add the androidx test core dependencies `testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'` to your `build.gradle`
After this you can use the `ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()` method

Comment: But I am not able to access it in Local Unit Test Cases. I was using Robolectric library with RuntimeEnvironment.application. This says it's deprecated and the soultion is to use ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(). But how do I access it in as the libraries marked with androidTestImplementation are accessible in androidTests (Instrumentation Test Cases) only. Please guide. Reference - https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project#android-test-dependencies

Comment: It's a bad practice to have a Context instance in Unit Test. Please mock the context in Unit Test if you need them there with Mockito or Mockk for Kotlin. Maybe you have to refactored your code so that you pass the context (or mock in the test) as parameter  in your method.